# How to Save data from a HTML/PHP Form to a Text file

Tags: php, html

I have a form that sends information to an email via a php file.

My HTML form is as below:

```
<form method="post" action="start-project.php">
<fieldset>
<span><input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required/></span>
<span><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" required/></span>
<span><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required/></span>
<span><input type="text" name="website" id="website" placeholder="Website (Optional)" /></span>
</fieldset>
<span><input type="submit" name="submit" value="GET STARTED"></span>
</form>
```

and my php code is as below:

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "email@domain.com";
$EmailTo = "receiver@email.com";
$Subject = "Submission: Start a Project";
$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone'])); 
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$website = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['website'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Website: ";
$Body .= $website;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=sent.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

How can I have the entry data to be save in a text file on the server?
I have seen few articles but I don't know how to implement it with my code.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Just to mention, it works and sends the email. I just want this additional option to save the entry in a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
 $log = file_put_contents('logs.txt', $name.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Thanks for the care to share this with me. I am not advanced with php codes. Where in my php file should I put this code?

Comment: This line will add `$name` into your text file, then go to new line. You'd need several lines with a different variable to make sure you save all the variables you want to keep.

Comment: `.PHP_EOL` adds a new line at the end of your `$name`, `FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX` make sure you're not deleting what was in the file previously, and locks the file so if 2 people send a mail at once, your script doesn't crash

Answer (score 1):

**If you use fopen() on a file that does not exist, it will create it,**

```
$file= "file.txt";
$fh = fopen($file, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "new data 1\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
$stringData = "New data 2\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append the data into a text file:

```
$myfile = fopen('files/file.txt', 'a');
fwrite($myfile, $data);
fclose($myfile);
```

> [php.net](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.fwrite.php) link

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone who helped.

I found this solution and it worked fine with me. 
I am putting it here in case if anyone came across it.

I added the code below in my php code after opening of PHP tag:

```
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['phone']) && isset($_POST['website'])) {
    $data = $_POST['name'] . ' - ' . $_POST['email'] . ' - ' . $_POST['phone'] . ' - ' . $_POST['website'] . "\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('file.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
```